# .Net web service with authentication

Tags: .net, web-services

i'm new to WCF .net i'm working with 3.5 VB.Net
so i have to create a Web service with an authentication
i used message and username security here is my web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="Binding1">
    <security mode="Message">
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
    </security>
  </binding>        
 </wsHttpBinding>
```

```
<services>
  <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="Behavior1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="MyWebSite"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Behavior1">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="MyWebSite"
                      storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                      storeName="My"
                      x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
             <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                 customUserNamePasswordValidatorType= "CustomUsernamePasswordAuth, App_Code" />
            </serviceCredentials>

        </behavior>             
    </serviceBehaviors>

</behaviors>
```

when i test this service on the client side i get an error telling me that the "an error has occred and the message security coud not be verified 
after some research i found this problem is due to synchronization between client and the server( my machine) but the two machine are perfectly synchronized they have exactly the same datetime i'm lost :(

Comment: Thy the above http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405740.aspx